# Can I make this SQL query more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have an SQL query which works fine, but I feel like there must be a more efficient way of writing it. By joining two tables A and B that contain coordinates, I am comparing distances (in metres) between each coordinate. I then sum/count the number of coordinates in table B that are within set distances of coordinates in table A and output the result:

```
select a.name,
       sum(case when ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84(ST_SetSRID(ST_LineString(a.lat, a.lon, b.lat, b.lon),4326)) < 10.0 then 1 else 0 end) 10mCount,
       sum(case when ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84(ST_SetSRID(ST_LineString(a.lat, a.lon, b.lat, b.lon),4326)) < 50.0 then 1 else 0 end) 50mCount,
       sum(case when ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84(ST_SetSRID(ST_LineString(a.lat, a.lon, b.lat, b.lon),4326)) < 1000.0 then 1 else 0 end) 1000mCount 
FROM a JOIN
     b
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER by 1000mCount desc
LIMIT 10;
```

I feel like there must be a way to call `ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84(ST_SetSRID(ST_LineString(a.lat, a.lon, b.lat, b.lon), 4326))` once, get the result and then increment each 10m, 50m and 1000m count.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: You haven't specified any join criteria - do you really want a cross join (every row in a joined to every row in b)?

Comment: your right, I just realised I don't need a join. But is the way that im doing the sum(case when) approach the most efficient way?

Comment: **I don't need a join** well you already have a join in place - it is an inefficient join (it is a `cross join`). You need a better join that will make your query more efficient.

Comment: @mike if you don't need a join, why are you using table "b"'s lat and long? Is table "b" actually table "a" but a specific row? ie are you trying to find how many near neighbors there are to a specific location (ie row) in a table of locations?

Comment: I'm writing a script that must process each coordinate/row in table A to identify how many of the coordinates/rows in table B are within a specific distance (i.e. 10, 50, 1000m).

Comment: @mike what are the approximate minimum and maximum latitudes expected in your data? (the answer matters quite a lot by the way, so if it can be reasonably restricted, especially to be as far from the poles as possible, please say so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try prequerying, but your data is STILL requiring the results to go through EVERY RECORD.

```
select
      PreQuery.name,
      sum(case when PreQuery.Geode < 10.0 then 1 else 0 end) 10mCount,
      sum(case when PreQuery.Geode < 50.0 then 1 else 0 end) 50mCount,
      sum(case when PreQuery.Geode < 1000.0 then 1 else 0 end) 1000mCount 
   from
      ( select 
              a.name,
              ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84( ST_SetSRID( ST_LineString(a.lat, a.lon, b.lat, b.lon),4326)) as Geode
           from 
              a join b  
                 (YOU ARE MISSING the JOIN 'ON' clause... how related) ) PreQuery
   GROUP BY 
      PreQuery.name
   ORDER by 
      1000mCount desc
   LIMIT 10;
```